# How to make all resources files in Android archive library public in my app android

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-resources, android-library, aar

I have created an android application and now I want to use some activities from it in another application as part of a new app. 
I get following error. How can I solve this?

[image: Error]

Comment: Post your logcat

Answer (score 0):

Do you compile the library as a jar file? or add it as a module. adding it as a module makes it easy to access those resources.

Comment: you mean this "compile project(":app-debug")" i added aar as library in my app but resources ex. home_menu.xml and styles not found, why ?